# Creating a polyhedron filled with points in face-centered cubic structure

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d, curated-data, polyhedra, lattices

I am relatively new to Mathematica, and I am trying to build a 3D polyhedron model filled with points in a face-centered cubic (fcc) pattern that shall represent atoms. I am running on Mathematica 11.3.

First I generate the fcc lattice points (excluding the centre):

```
fcc = Select[Tuples[Range[-5, 5], {3}], EvenQ[Total[#]] &];
list = Select[fcc, Norm[#] > 0 &];
```

Then the boundary of a polyhedron is discretized using:

```
bnd = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"];
reg = RegionMember @ bnd;
```

And lastly, only points are picked which are in the specified region.

```
atoms = Pick[list, reg @ list, True]
```

But the list created at this step remains empty. Initially, I thought it might be caused by the fixed size `PolyhedronData` assigns to `Dodecahedron`. Besides the fact the `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` does not accept scaled polyhedra, it still seems not to work if one would try to go with:

```
0.5*list
```

Anyone an idea what is happening?

Comment: Who or what is "fcc"? Please explain. Maybe you mean a face-centered cubic lattice?

Comment: Did you know you could just use `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]`?

Comment: fcc means face-centered cubic structure, a Bravais-lattice used to describe solid matter crystallographically, such as metals. Sorry for not explaining that point directly.

Comment: You just have to scale the lattice like so: `fcc = 0.125 Select[Tuples[Range[-20, 20], {3}], EvenQ[Total[#]] &];` and then continue as before.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. for that suggestion, indeed I have overseen that in the documentation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thank you for your help! Indeed that works, but I am just wondering why I was not able to scale the lattice via 0.5*list? Is there a particular reason scaling has to be done directly in that line? 
Is there a solution where the lattice scale is left constant, but the polyhedron is scaled to fit in all points (although it might be tricky bypassing the restriction from BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics)?

Comment: Oh, `Select[list/2, reg]` _does_ work, so does `atoms = Pick[list/2, reg[list/2]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of summarizing the solutions and suggestions provided in the comments, and using your definitions of `fcc`, `list`, `reg`, then either of the following would work:

```
atoms = Select[list/2, reg]
atoms = Pick[list/2, reg[list/2]]
```

Without having to discretize, you can extract a region membership criterion directly from   `PolyhedronData`, [as suggested by @JM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194429/creating-a-polyhedron-filled-with-points-in-fcc-structure#comment506224_194429):

```
atoms = Select[list/2, Apply@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]]
```

I want to point out a seeming inconsistency here; I would have expected `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "RegionFunction"]` to return an object that behaves like a `RegionMemberFunction` (call it `rmf`), which would take lists as arguments, e.g. `rmf[{x, y, z}]`. However, `PolyhedronData` returns a pure function that expects coordinate arguments *as a sequence* instead, i.e. `rmf[x, y, z]`. Hence the need for the `Apply` in the `Select` expression above.